# how to get text from richboxtext silverlight

Tags: silverlight, richtext

How can I get text from a RichTextBox Control in silverlight?

I'd search a lot but I cant find the way... :(

Comment: Pretty sure you need to read the [`.Xaml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.xaml%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property, but I may be wrong. _See also the [Silverlight RichTextBox Editor Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426926%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)_ -- Another interesting demo site [can be found here](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/index.htm#/?sref=HomePage).

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it can be:

```
rtb.SelectAll();
var myText = rtb.Selection.Text;
```